# Why does Awk's print acts crazy in formating two simple piped fields?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Good Evening.

I encountered a strange phenomenon in dealing with awk's last field that I want to share it with you.
I have a log file for social networks which contains some fields separated by |.
The fields are not important imho but they appear in this formating.
id|name|lastname|...|Social_Media_Used(nothing)
There are 9 separate fields.

Every row contains a user. e.g. ^random_numbers|Aris|something|...|Facebook$

The goal is to find a way of finding a total for every social media used.I have done this using the above code.

```
grep -v '^#' $3 | awk -F\| '{print $9}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $1$2}'
```

First command removes # from my file that are considered comments.

Second command finds and prints the field 9 which corresponds at the field 
**Social_Media_Used**.This is the last field so I guess it will have \n at the end.

After that I sort and count the field and last awk prints the output like this:

```
884Blogger  
1105Facebook  
1326Flickr  
1104Google+  
1105Instagram  
1105LinkedIn  
1325Twitter  
1546Youtube
```

If I try in the last this command:
awk '{print $2$1}' then something strange happens.
If I store it it in a file I can see it like this:

```
Blogger  
 884  
Facebook  
 1105  
Flickr  
 1326  
Google+  
 1104  
Instagram  
 1105
LinkedIn  
 1105  
Twitter  
 1325  
Youtube  
 1546
```

If howerer I try to see the output form from terminal I see this:

```
884gger  
1105book  
1326kr  
1104le+  
1105agram  
1105edIn  
1325ter  
1546ube
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT IS:**
    Blogger 884
    Facebook 1105
    Flickr 1326
    Google+ 1104
    Instagram 1105
    LinkedIn 1105
    Twitter 1325
    Youtube 1546

I searched everything about sed or awk's RS,ORS or FRS and I also tried with printf or print but I couldn't find anything that matched or even came close to have word-space-number in the same line.No matter how I print or printf these lines.Howewer, when I try to print a dummy file I copy-pasted from main with 20 lines everything goes smoothly.Also, everything goes smoothly if I try to printf or print the field 8 or 7.

Where lies the solution to this problem?In the long file of 9500 files?Or in the fact that exists newline after the word?What do you think?

Comment: Please add sample input (multiple rows) and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: one word `dos2unix`

Comment: ... or `awk -v RS="\r?\n" ...`

Comment: multichar RS requires GNU `awk`

Comment: @JamesBrown: You were a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

your data most likely include `\r\n` line endings. First run `dos2unix file`

you can eliminate most of the pipes with this as well

```
$ awk -F\| '!/^#/{a[$9]++} END{for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file | sort
```

Comment: '!/^#/ does remove one pipe it's true.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Replace with GNU awk:

```
awk '{print $2$1}'
```

with

```
awk -v RS='\r*\n' '{print $2$1}'
```

to handle Unix and DOS/Windows line endings.

Comment: Thank you very much!My code (after a comma between) works perfectly.

Comment: A small detail improvement: replace `*` with `{0,1}`